# WSO2 APIM Analytics SQL Server Installation

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to run the APIM Analytics but want to go away from default H2 databases and use SQL Server instead.
Here are the mappings of the database in SQL Server:

```
${sys:carbon.home}/wso2/dashboard/database/metrics ---> WSO2_APIM_ANALYTICS_METRICS
${sys:carbon.home}/wso2/${sys:wso2.runtime}/database/WSO2_CARBON_DB --> WSO2_APIM_ANALYTICS_CARBON
${sys:carbon.home}/wso2/dashboard/database/MESSAGE_TRACING_DB --> WSO2_APIM_ANALYTICS_MESSAGE_TRACING
${sys:carbon.home}/wso2/worker/database/GEO_LOCATION_DATA --> WSO2_APIM_ANALYTICS_GEO_LOCATION_DATA
${sys:carbon.home}/wso2/worker/database/WSO2AM_MGW_ANALYTICS_DB --> WSO2_APIM_ANALYTICS_MICROGATEWAY_ANALYTICS
${sys:carbon.home}/wso2/${sys:wso2.runtime}/database/SP_MGT_DB --> WSO2_APIM_ANALYTICS_SP_MGT_DB
${sys:carbon.home}/wso2/${sys:wso2.runtime}/database/DASHBOARD_DB --> WSO2_APIM_ANALYTICS_DASHBOARD
${sys:carbon.home}/wso2/${sys:wso2.runtime}/database/SAMPLE_DB --> WSO2_APIM_ANALYTICS_SAMPLE
${sys:carbon.home}/wso2/${sys:wso2.runtime}/database/wso2_status_dashboard --> WSO2_APIM_ANALYTICS_STATUS_DASHBOARD
${sys:carbon.home}/wso2/worker/database/WSO2AM_STATS_DB --> WSO2_METRICS
${sys:carbon.home}/wso2/${sys:wso2.runtime}/database/BUSINESS_RULES_DB --> WSO2_APIM_ANALYTICS_BUSINESS_RULES
${sys:carbon.home}/wso2/${sys:wso2.runtime}/database/PERMISSION_DB --> WSO2_APIM_ANALYTICS_PERMISSIONS
${sys:carbon.home}/wso2/worker/database/WSO2AM_MGW_ANALYTICS_DB --> WSO2_APIM_ANALYTICS_MICROGATEWAY_ANALYTICS
${sys:carbon.home}/wso2/worker/database/GEO_LOCATION_DATA --> WSO2_APIM_ANALYTICS_GEO_LOCATION_DATA
```

I updated deployment.yaml for all three worker, manager and dashboard functionality to point to a new data source.

When I try to run the worker.bat, I get the following error messages for sidhi. It looks like schema and data for other databases are not populated as it is for h2. 
How can I get the schema for all the databases that h2 uses and populate in SQL Server?

I also opened h2 database but don't see anything in h2 database in public schema. Am I missing something?

Here are the errors I see when I start the worker node:

```
{org.wso2.transport.http.netty.listener.ServerConnectorBootstrap$HTTPServerConnector} - HTTP(S) Interface starting on host 0.0.0.0 and port 9444
    [2019-04-09 14:22:59,446] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorDeployer} - org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.SiddhiAppCreationException: Error on 'apim_abnormal_backend_time_alert_0' @ Line: 34. Position: 111, near '@store(type = 'rdbms', datasource = 'APIM_ANALYTICS_DB')
    define table ApimAllAlert (type string, tenantDomain string, message string, severity int, alertTimestamp long)'. No extension exist for store:rdbms org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.exception.SiddhiAppDeploymentException: org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.SiddhiAppCreationException: Error on 'apim_abnormal_backend_time_alert_0' @ Line: 34. Position: 111, near '@store(type = 'rdbms', datasource = 'APIM_ANALYTICS_DB')
    define table ApimAllAlert (type string, tenantDomain string, message string, severity int, alertTimestamp long)'. No extension exist for store:rdbms
            at org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorDeployer.deploySiddhiQLFile(StreamProcessorDeployer.java:105)
            at org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorDeployer.deploy(StreamProcessorDeployer.java:306)
            at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine.lambda$deployArtifacts$0(DeploymentEngine.java:291)
            at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
            at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine.deployArtifacts(DeploymentEngine.java:282)
            at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.RepositoryScanner.sweep(RepositoryScanner.java:112)
            at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.RepositoryScanner.scan(RepositoryScanner.java:68)
            at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine.start(DeploymentEngine.java:121)
            at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngineListenerComponent.onAllRequiredCapabilitiesAvailable(DeploymentEngineListenerComponent.java:216)
            at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.lambda$notifySatisfiableComponents$7(StartupComponentManager.java:266)
            at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
            at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.notifySatisfiableComponents(StartupComponentManager.java:252)
            at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupOrderResolver$1.run(StartupOrderResolver.java:204)
            at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
            at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
    Caused by: org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.SiddhiAppCreationException: Error on 'apim_abnormal_backend_time_alert_0' @ Line: 34. Position: 111, near '@store(type = 'rdbms', datasource = 'APIM_ANALYTICS_DB')
    define table ApimAllAlert (type string, tenantDomain string, message string, severity int, alertTimestamp long)'. No extension exist for store:rdbms
            at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.SiddhiClassLoader.loadExtensionImplementation(SiddhiClassLoader.java:45)
            at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.helper.DefinitionParserHelper.addTable(DefinitionParserHelper.java:203)
            at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.SiddhiAppRuntimeBuilder.defineTable(SiddhiAppRuntimeBuilder.java:125)
            at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SiddhiAppParser.defineTableDefinitions(SiddhiAppParser.java:320)
            at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SiddhiAppParser.parse(SiddhiAppParser.java:224)
            at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:65)
            at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:74)
            at org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorService.deploySiddhiApp(StreamProcessorService.java:100)
            at org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorDeployer.deploySiddhiQLFile(StreamProcessorDeployer.java:93)
            ... 14 more
```

And many more like this for each alert types.
Any help in regards to this is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The tables needed will be created in most of the cases, exceptions are following data sources and those needs to be created only if you are using the specific functionality, 
1. Metrics DB
2. Microgateway analytics db

However, seems the issue you are facing is the server is not recognising siddhi-store-rdbms.jar packed in /lib folder. Please check if it is available. It is packed by default.

Answer (score 0):

Niveathika,
We are currently not using microgateway functionality so I really don't know if I need to have that database populated with schema but what I found was that I have to have two database schema populated WSO2_APIM_ANALYTICS_GEO_LOCATION_DATA and WSO2_APIM_ANALYTICS_DASHBOARD I found schema for WSO2_APIM_ANALYTICS_DASHBOARD in stream processor server
Here are those two schema for someone like me struggling to migrate over to MSSQL

**WSO2_APIM_ANALYTICS_DASHBOARD**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[DASHBOARD_RESOURCE]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [dbo].[DASHBOARD_RESOURCE]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DASHBOARD_RESOURCE](
  [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [URL] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [OWNER] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [NAME] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
  [DESCRIPTION] [varchar](1000) NULL,
  [PARENT_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [LANDING_PAGE] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [CONTENT] [varbinary](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DASHBOARD_RESOURCE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
  [URL] ASC,
  [OWNER] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[WIDGET_RESOURCE]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [dbo].[WIDGET_RESOURCE]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WIDGET_RESOURCE](
  [WIDGET_ID] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
  [WIDGET_NAME] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
  [WIDGET_CONFIGS] [varbinary](8000) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_WIDGET_RESOURCE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
  [WIDGET_ID] ASC,
  [WIDGET_NAME] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**WSO2_APIM_ANALYTICS_GEO_LOCATION_DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE BLOCKS (
    network_cidr varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    network BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
      broadcast BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
     geoname_id BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
      registered_country_geoname_id BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
      represented_country_geoname_id BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
      is_anonymous_proxy SMALLINT DEFAULT '0',
      is_satellite_provider SMALLINT DEFAULT '0',
      postal_code VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      latitude DECIMAL(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
      longitude DECIMAL(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
    network_blocks varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL);

CREATE INDEX idx_blocks_network ON BLOCKS (network);
CREATE INDEX idx_blocks_broadcast ON BLOCKS (broadcast);
CREATE INDEX idx_blocks_network_blocks ON BLOCKS (network_blocks);

CREATE TABLE LOCATION (
      geoname_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
      locale_code VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      continent_code VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      continent_name VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      country_iso_code VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      country_name VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      subdivision_1_iso_code VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      subdivision_1_name VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
      subdivision_2_iso_code VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      subdivision_2_name VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
      city_name VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
      metro_code BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
      time_zone VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (geoname_id));

CREATE TABLE IP_LOCATION (
      ip VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
      country_name VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
      city_name VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (ip)
);
```

Thanks